Receiving a list of objects with files on Spring Boot
I made a question before to receive a list of custom objects on Spring Boot on multipart/form-data requests. Now, I need to make some adjustments to send files as well
Before, I was sending the list field as a JSON, so a custom converter was enough to handle the task. But it won't work for files. So I found this answer on how to handle the POST of arrays/lists of objects (they used NextJS as the backend) and I'd like to do something similar for Spring, and can't find any answers as well. Here is an exemple of how the request should look:

Or, if you need a JS example:
function createFormData() {
    const formDate = new FormData()

    formDate.append('name', 'test')
    formDate.append('logo', new File([''], 'test.png'))
    formDate.append('link', 'test')

    formDate.append('contacts[0][name]', 'test')
    formDate.append('contacts[0][email]', 'test')
    formDate.append('contacts[0][icon]', new File([''], 'test.png'))

    formDate.append('contacts[1][name]', 'test')
    formDate.append('contacts[1][email]', 'test')
    formDate.append('contacts[1][icon]', new File([''], 'test.png'))

    return formDate
}

When receiving a request like this, Spring returns:
Invalid property 'contacts[0][email]' of bean class [com.example.trilha.dto.PartnerRequest]: Illegal attempt to get property 'contacts' threw exception
How can I implement this?
My route is the following:
@PostMapping(value = "createPartner", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<String> createPartner(
        @ModelAttribute PartnerRequest partnerRequest
) 

The DTOs for the request are the following:
record Contacts(
        String name,
        String email,
        MultipartFile icon
) {}

public record PartnerRequest(
        String name,
        MultipartFile logo,
        String link,
        List<Contact> contacts
){}

EDIT:
I do not have a front-end right now, I'm creating and testing the API first before build the interface
Changing ModelAttribute to RequestParam does not solve the problem, because Spring will try to read as a JSON (thus won't handle the file upload)


any error you are getting? and how you pass the file and other details?

@Akari Oozora Could you try using @RequestPart instead of @ModelAttribute and see if that helps since now it is more than key value pairs as stated here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html? Could you also add your form setup on the front end to be able to see how it is being sent to the endpoint?

@Vaibs I detailed the error as well how the contents are being passed now. @heyo this has been detailed on the edit, unfortunately, @RequestPart can't handle the files

So, I found a way to do this and it isn't good in any way. Won't work if you need to nest it with something else and is more code to mantain
Essentially, I take the request and parse it myself
@PostMapping(value = "createPartner", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<String> createPartner(
        MultipartHttpServletRequest request
) throws Exception {
    try {
        PartnerRequest prq = PartnerRequestParser.parse(request);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Ok");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().body(e.getMessage());
    }
}

The parser is trivial code, you take each field and assign to the object:
String name = request.getParameter("name");

return new PartnerRequest(name, ...); 

For the list of objects, you have to iterate over each index like this:
List<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

int index = 0;
while (request.getParameter("contacts[" + index + "][name]") != null) {
    contacts.add(new Contacts(
            request.getParameter("contacts[" + index + "][name]"),
            request.getFile("contacts[" + index + "][icon]"),
    ));
    index++;
}


I had a very similar problem about a year ago which I solved the following way:
First of all you don't need any converter or any other special code, you can simply add the following controller method:
    @PostMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadFile(
        @PathVariable UUID id, // If you need PathVariables you can do it like this
        @RequestPart(value = "metadata") Object metadata, //This can be any complex Java-Object, you can also use the concrete type here. I use it to store additional information.
        @RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file, //This is your file
        @RequestParam(value = "index") int index, //This is any form field, you can add as many as you want or leave it out.
) {
    // Do stuff
}

And that´s all.
As a sidenode, if you don´t need the metadata leave it out. If you need it you need make sure the client sends it correctly otherwise you will run into trouble. For example this is how I create my FormData in Typescript:
  private createUploadBody(
    file: File,
    metadata: any,
    index: number
  ): FormData {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);

    if (metadata) {
      const json = JSON.stringify(metadata);
      const blob = new Blob([json], {
        type: 'application/json',
      });
      formData.append('metadata', blob);
    }

    formData.append('index', `${index}`);

    return formData;
  }

For the Contact-List you should try to read it as a @RequestParam, but you might need to go the Metadata route  and send it as a JSON-Blob. I am not sure if lists can be handled correctly as a @RequestParam.
Edit: just realized the Contact-List is a list of complex object so you probably need to use @RequestPart. You can use your PartnerRequest without the Multipart file if you want and simply send it as a JSON Blob.

I can't replicate your example to match the way I'm trying to do this. I edited to show how the JS/TS FormData should look. Also, I'd like to not split the contents in the controller such as @RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file, because there are other routes that will receive PartnerRequest alongside other custom DTOs
